# Changing Music on a Cuckoo Clock Movement

Tags: integrated-circuit, sound

A band has asked me to design a cuckoo clock for them that plays a piece of their music, to sell to their fans. Movements that just cuckoo and also movements that play music in addition are readily available.
The basic movement sounds a cuckoo call on the hour and half hour as the cuckoo goes in and out. A musical movement has the addition of a carousel (the dancers you see on the front) going round as the music is played. So all of the triggers are there.
[Here's the movement.](https://new.blackforestimports.com/advancedwebpage.aspx?cg=529&cd=4&SKUTYPE=202&SKUFLD=SKU&WEBID=2966)
[Here's a clock in action](https://cuckoomeister.com/products/quartz-cuckoo-clock-black-forest-house-with-moving-dancers-and-music-by-trenkle) (scroll down a little for the video)
Rather than having to order these custom in thousands from China via Germany, could it be that the chip in the movement could be swapped out on this end for one with the band's music?
Thanks for any light anyone can shed on this,

Jodie

Edit: Added an image of the board.[image]

Comment: What chip is it that you think can be swapped out. I doubt that anyone on this site has one of these clocks and you are likely to be in possession of one. Have you tried reverse engineering the circuit diagram? Are you experienced enough for this job? It might be easier to get the band to record a series of cuckoos as a music track then no modification is necessary.

Comment: I have zero experience or ability. It's a complete unknown to me.

Comment: That's a fun idea but this is a big name 80's/90's band. We've worked out a design using a particular song of theirs. It actually opens a different side to my business of traditional weight-driven cuckoo clocks as other bands will want clocks too. My problem is I am only up on the 200+ year old technology.

Comment: Just so you aren't spinning your wheels, pretty much the market rate is $100/hr for consultants.  At a minimum, I would guess that is at least 100 hours of work from end to end...  If your band thinks there is $10,000 of sales here, awesome.  If not, looking around for a pre-existing board is going to be WAY MORE cost effective.  ALSO -- you'll have to design the plastic enclosure and build a mold ($15k). So minimum $25K. You may find a Chinese company willing pull it together, but they will own the design and copy it for other customers if there is market.

Comment: Sounds like a cool idea, not trying to be a hater.  This stuff costs a lot more than you may initially think...  I own a company building similar products (chips in plastics), and we live these numbers all the time.

Comment: You're not a hater! If the reality is that it's too expensive I'd rather know that now.

Comment: This isn't a design problem, this is a manufacturing problem.  If you just needed a handful or could tolerate a high unit cost there are various ways to combine multiple parts, but by the time you solve the power issues and build them, it's practical for the described need.  Instead, you need to find a factory that makes these and get a quote on a custom run.

Comment: Reminds me of the electronics group in my university where we hacked the musical horn of the department car. Initial plan was to reprogram the memory with a new tune, but we ended up using a micro and a capacitor array to store the analog tune and the micro to clock it out. Good times.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of very cheap sound circuit boards you can order. Many of them can store multiple song movements to be accessed separately. They are very cheap and relatively easy to "program" with audio of your choosing. But they would have to be adapted to these clocks.

These clocks almost certainly include something quite similar, but custom pre-programmed. You might get lucky enough that boards you can find (from China, Taiwan, etc) are very close in terms of voltages, connections, etc., that they could be easily applied to the standard clock to re-make it in your desired image.

But you might be unlucky enough where the circuits/boards they use are different enough that it will take at least *some* very specific design knowledge in order to adapt them. In fact, that's a likely scenario. And for that, you will *first* need to get someone who will examine a standard clock for you and tell you how likely that option might be. And then, if you decide to go there, would be responsible for completing the project for you.

In short, my recommendation is that you break things into the following steps:

1. Find a consultant, one that you can count on to complete, to examine one of these standard clocks with the standard song choices. Ask them to prepare a report or plan about the next steps available to you. This report will include the results of their examination (what kind of method is used in the clock to trigger the songs and/or select them) and perhaps one, two, or even three approaches that might succeed in achieving your goals. Those approaches should include some idea of the downside risks in terms of time and money, as well as the upside benefits. Make sure the consultant realizes that you may, or may not, select them for the final work and that you want a report that can be taken to others for the purposes of bidding the job, if your group decides to go that way.
2. [See text below (*)]
3. Sit down with your group, study the report, and decide on a course of further action. Then follow through, either with your consultant finishing the project or else bidding it out using the report as a basis.

(*) If you want to see if EESE can be used as a cheap source of advice, that report would go a long, long way in helping others here understand the situation better. And you can then get a lot of free kibbitzing, which may or may not help much. So you could insert a "kibbitz" period before bidding out the project or hiring your consultant, I suppose. But I wouldn't count any chickens here and it may only wind up delaying things or adding emotions to an already emotional situation, perhaps. Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely you'll be able to "swap the chip". You'd be better off going either with disabling the sound altogether or using a movement without any music, then using a separate circuit to generate the music. You need somebody with electronics capabilities to design this addition/modification. But realistically you're now looking at a professionally manufactured production run. Mods suitable for a one off hobby project aren't much use if you want to sell them commercially.

Comment: I was hoping it'd be simple.  But maybe the China route is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to swap the chip.

But as it's an electromechanical movement, there must be a mechanical switch that generates a pulse lasting either about a second or a relatively short time, maybe a minute or so, to tell the birdie to pop out, or to drive the carousel.

You can almost certainly use a pulse to start a recording, or the minute long signal to power a ready made music playing device. These are [cheaply available from the usual sources](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ISD1820-Sound-Voice-Recording-Playback-Module-Arduino-PI-0-5W-Loudspeaker-UK/262460535768?epid=507767793&hash=item3d1bddf3d8:g:E~wAAOSw705Z4fAf), and some of them allow you to record and store music samples via your computer (perhaps via a programmer).

Whether this one is good enough I can't say. I don't even know if this one forgets the recording when it loses power; obviously you need one with [non-volatile storage (this one has)](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ISD1700-Series-Voice-Record-Play-ISD1760-Module-For-AVR-Arduino-PIC-CF/272247684341?hash=item3f6339fcf5:g:4ygAAOSwAahXPTpo). And you'll want to transfer the music via an audio lead rather than via microphone.

Some experimentation required. If a few £/$ of clock movement and electronics and an afternoon's hacking doesn't yield a result, consider a consultant as the other answers suggest.

Comment: It's got to be non-volatile so the audio is retained when changing batteries.Thanks for giving it a name! The movements arrived. I popped one open to see the circuit board. Added a photo to my original post.

Comment: aka "Flash" memory, as in the second advert I listed (search vendors for that chip number).

Comment: Which chip number?

Comment: ISD1700. I'd buy one of those modules to experiment with. The ISD1820 might be non volatile too, the ad listings didn't say. But https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwii_PuIzt_YAhVDWRQKHYEYA8MQFgguMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhackerstore.nl%2FPDFs%2FEIM353_ISD1820_Module_Manual_V01.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0hv1Xjk0ydpGEdz-hrlsI3 says it is - so either of those modules may work.